# How do I increase performance of Django Project with huge data?

Tags: python, django, google-maps

I have 4 models, one is main model which will have only some info and remaining 4 models will have multiple data like images, reviews, contacts.
Now, I need to pass/render complete data to templates like Main model data and remaining models data which have foreign key of main mode.
I wrote some function to prepare the data in format, which includes every model data.
This function will loop over the all results of Main model and then will get the sub models data and will arrange the data in dict format.

Because of this function, it's taking huge time to prepare the data.

Also I have map page like in google map page, with multiple markers and side multiple places to display.
here also I am losing performance, because of multiple markers.

So I thought to implement Lazy loading,

Can any one suggest me, what I can do to increase the performance?

Answer (score 1):

A common solution for this kind of problem is to use some caching (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/cache/)

Comment: Hi @bruno , before setting up a cache I would suggest optimizing joins with correct use of `select_related` and `prefetch_related` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#select-related . This may dramatically improve performances when looping through models with relations.

Comment: Hello @JérômeThiard you're of course right - actually that seems so obvious that I assumed this had already been done ;)